# Change of a coordinate system : Translation of the origin

Tags: geometry

First post. Please be nice.

I have a set of 2d points in a coordinate system. I would like to get their coordinates in a new coordinate system whose origin corresponds to a translation of the current origin.

I solved it geometrically by drawing my two coordinate systems on top of each other.
Then for each point, I saw the new coordinates corresponded to the coordinates of the vector that is the addition of :

- The vector that corresponds to my point in the current coordinate system

- `+`

- The inverse vector of the vector that translates the origin to the new origin.

However the geometrical solution does not work if the two coordinates systems do not have the same orientation.

For example I don't understand the formula in **The Canvas** section of [this](https://www.gabrielgambetta.com/computer-graphics-from-scratch/01-common-concepts.html) page. I see that it works but I would like to find why it works.

Is there a way to solve it numerically or a more general proof ?

Feel free to edit my post with latex formatting or anything you can think of to make it clearer. I promise I will check out your edits in order to learn proper formatting.

Comment: That’s right. Since the origin is translated by a vector $\vec v$, all points in space get translated by the same vector. Then to undo that change, you need to add $-\vec v$ to all points.

Comment: But how do you find v when the tow coordinate system do not share the same orientation ?